# How to detect and remove obsolete items in a programmatically generated Chef data bag?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a following Chef definition which creates a per-node data bag and populates it with node-related items:

```
define :nagios_monitor, :command => "command", :description => "", :mon_name => "" do
    if not Chef::DataBag.list.key?(node[:hostname] + "_nagios_services")
        new_databag = Chef::DataBag.new
        new_databag.name(node[:hostname] + "_nagios_services")
        new_databag.save
    end
    databag = Chef::DataBag.list[node[:hostname] + "_nagios_services"]

    payload = {
        "id" => params[:mon_name],
        "command" => params[:command],
        "description" => params[:description]
    }
    databag_item = Chef::DataBagItem.new
    databag_item.data_bag(node[:hostname] + "_nagios_services")
    databag_item.raw_data = payload
    databag_item.save
end
```

It works well when I add new `nagios_monitor` resources to cookbooks but it does not detect resource removals. I guess I should iterate over data bag items somewhere in the code to check if an item still exists in my configuration but I just can't find a proper place for this. What is a canonical way of purging obsolete items from data bags?

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck solving similar problems by dropping the whole bag, and then regenerating it entirely. This really only works if you have a single writer though.